# Is it possible to make a graph that shows number of contacts over time?

Tags: reporting, contact, dashboard

We want to add to a dashboard a graph showing how many contacts are in a report over time. So in May there were 12,000, in June 13,000, in Aug 12,500.

I can create the report that shows how many contacts *today* but I don't see a way of getting the historical data. Would I have to create a report for each month? How could I sum them into a single graph for display on a dashboard?

Comment: Did you tried analytical snapshot ?

Comment: do you want to plot the data based on createddate of the contact? like those created date falls on Mar, it will be counted in March and total contact count will show all the sum till March

Comment: Yeah, basically want to track how we're doing in getting new contacts/leads over time as an organization

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've been storing this historical data, there's no way to get this report. You can start from today by using an analytical snapshot, outlined in [Report on Historical Data with Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US&type=0). Basically, create a custom object with the fields for data you want to store, build a report that shows the data you want to be able to show over time, then schedule the analytic snapshot to occur on a frequency. You will then be able to report on historical data.

Comment: Wow, this looks like it does what I want, but man, is it *not* simple. But, then again, is Salesforce ever?

Comment: @bombcar It only *looks* complicated. It really only takes a few minutes to set up, and is fully automated afterwards.

Comment: I'll have to trust you on that, all salesforce docs make things look like they require an Act of God to implement.